# How to maintain (top) row visible while scrolling?

Tags: libreoffice, spreadsheet

I did it once, but cannot find out how any more:

how to keep the top row of my LibreOffice Calc sheet visible when scrolling?

(Intuitively it should be either in view or format, at best in right-click menu, but I can't see anything related ... )

Comment: Seems like this should be migrated to SuperUser.

Comment: I've not understood the point of "SuperUser" so far. I wish there would me more thrust with opening a LibreOffice SE ...

Comment: Questions about software that runs on \*nix are [on-topic here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#questions)

Comment: @Benjamin, there is now http://ask.libreoffice.org but it has nothing to do with Stack Exchange.

Comment: While I agree that this question is on-topic here, it might reach more people on Super User given the fact LibreOffice also runs on other operating systems.

Comment: While the answer has been given, it may be worth noting that there is an enhancement request at https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=90961 to make this easier to find and more intuitive.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can achieve this by either **splitting** or **freezing** the spreadsheet. These two options are slightly different, the main difference being that splitting adds a second scrollbar, viewing the same sheet from two contiguous windows as it were.

## How to split the spreadsheet

#### Using the mouse pointer:

1. Drag the little black horizontal segment that is above the scroll bar, while dragging you will see an horizontal line moving;
2. Drop the line just under the selection you want to maintain fixed.

**Drag:**

[image: drag]

**and drop:**

[image: drop]

#### Using menus:

1. Select the row below the line where you want the split to appear;
2. Select *Window* > *Split*

## How to freeze the spreadsheet

1. Select the row below the row you want to freeze;
2. Select *Window* > *Freeze*

Comment: Thanks. I'm adding some pics to make it more visual. Do you know how to do that from menus?

Comment: @Benjamin: Position the cursor on first free row and select the menu item Windows->Freeze

Comment: Hey actually I found out that dragging the line is splitting the sheet, while the other option is freezing it. I'm going to edit the answer to give the different options if you don't have any objections.

Comment: @Benjamin: make your editing freely, if this improves the answer. I suggest to take your credit by starting with "Added by Benjamin:" or similar.

Comment: I don't worry about credits :) thanks.

Comment: @Benjamin You could also just add your own answer, but if the OP is ok with you merging your answer into this one I guess that works

Comment: Thanks Michael, i'll keep it simple. The point is that it can help people.

Comment: For `gnumeric` users, the freezing feature is available through [View > Freeze Panes](http://www.hep.by/gnu/gnumeric/View-Menu.shtml).

Comment: If you're using LibreOffice 5 (or at least 5.1.5.2 on OS X), the freezing options are now under `View > Freeze Rows and Columns` and `View > Split Window`

Comment: Also View > Freeze Cells > Freeze First Row